# How can I read my dependency from my class of a given type of Class/Inteface and execute methods on it?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to write a code. Where a message input handler will take a message and determine its working with the help of an enum object.

My enum object will contain details such identifier (Used for identification), Class (Which kind of dependency to execute), MethodName (Which method to run).

eg:- MAPPER1("1", Class1.class, "doSomething");

I have the message handler read the payload, Use identifier to identify the Enum, Get the dependency type and method from the enum and then execute it.

My intention is to make sure that the mapping (the identifier to class) is hardcoded somewhere, So it can be tracked and understood easily by the next developer.

Can you help me on how can I read the dependencies from my current Class, find the right dependency and then run it? Or is there any other option from Spring/Java that can help me with this.

I'm using a combination of spring framework and java.

Comment: Try google with keyword "spring framework dependency injection"

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Dependency injection would help to inject dependencies. The thing I'm looking for is to do an enum, Which I could read to identify the processing and not go through the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion from a tyro developer. I am not sure whether this would help you or not or even that you would be able to implement this in your code, but here goes - Use a Factory to actually get the dependency. You can make all your dependencies implement a common interface and then pass to the factory an identifier(which in your case I think would be the Enum) and use ApplicationContext to get required bean.

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceFactory {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext ctx;

public YourDependency createDependency(String identifier) {

    YourDependency yourDependency= null;

    switch (identifier) {
    case "1":
        yourDependency = ctx.getBean(YourDependency1.class);
        break;
    case "2":
        yourDependency = ctx.getBean(YourDependency2.class);
        break;
    case "3":
        yourDependency = ctx.getBean(YourDependency3.class);
        break;
    }
    return yourDependency;
}
}
```

And annotatre all your dependency classes with `@Component`
Please tell me if this helps and/or if you need any more clarification.